# Read vb script session in c# ashx file

Tags: c#, vb.net, session

I have some cms project wroten in visual basic, now i conected some file manager but its on c#.

So i want to make my file manager safe, so i want to check session which is set in vb file.

In vb i have no problem, when im calling:

```
If Session("IsAuthenticated") Is Nothing Then
```

This works. But if i want to call same session in c# script its empty i think. I tried:

```
if (Session["City"] == null) {
```

its allways null...

Comment: You're checking a different property in both script snippets, so start by using the same property of IsAuthenticated

Comment: Oh sorry its my mistake, i copied wrong if. But im checking same session key.

Comment: What project type is the File Manager?

Comment: This is roxy filemanager for dotnet

Comment: How is the C# code called? Have you considered passing `Session` as a parameter to the C# method?